# ClassCastException: EhCacheCacheManager cannot be cast to CacheManager

Tags: spring, ehcache, spring-cache

I wanted to monitor spring cache/ehcache with JMX mbeans, so I created following beans:

```
import java.lang.management.ManagementFactory;
import java.lang.management.ManagementFactory;
import java.util.List;

import javax.management.MBeanServer;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.cache.CacheManager;
import org.springframework.cache.annotation.EnableCaching;
import org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheCacheManager;
import org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheManagerFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.context.MessageSource;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan.Filter;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.DependsOn;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.FilterType;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.PropertySource;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.PropertySources;
import org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource;
import org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource;
import org.springframework.data.web.config.EnableSpringDataWebSupport;
import org.springframework.format.FormatterRegistry;
import org.springframework.http.converter.ByteArrayHttpMessageConverter;
import org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageConverter;
import org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter;
import org.springframework.validation.Validator;
import org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.LocalValidatorFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.MethodValidationPostProcessor;
import org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodArgumentResolver;
import org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodReturnValueHandler;
import org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartResolver;
import org.springframework.web.multipart.support.StandardServletMultipartResolver;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.HandlerExceptionResolver;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ViewResolver;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.InterceptorRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.ResourceHandlerRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.ViewControllerRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.hibernate5.Hibernate5Module;
import com.google.common.collect.Lists;

import net.sf.ehcache.management.ManagementService;

@EnableWebMvc
@EnableSpringDataWebSupport
@EnableCaching
@Configuration
public class SpringWebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    ...

    @Bean
    public CacheManager ehCacheManager() {
        EhCacheCacheManager cacheManager = new EhCacheCacheManager();
        cacheManager.setCacheManager((net.sf.ehcache.CacheManager) ehCacheManagerFactory().getObject());

        return cacheManager;
    }

    @Bean
    public EhCacheManagerFactoryBean ehCacheManagerFactory() {
        EhCacheManagerFactoryBean cmfb = new EhCacheManagerFactoryBean();
        cmfb.setConfigLocation(new ClassPathResource("ehcache.xml"));
        cmfb.setShared(true);
        return cmfb;
    }

    @Bean
    public ManagementService managementService() {
        return new ManagementService((net.sf.ehcache.CacheManager) ehCacheManager(), mBeanServer(), true, true, true, true);
    }


    @Bean
    public MBeanServer mBeanServer() {
        MBeanServer bean = ManagementFactory.getPlatformMBeanServer();
        return bean;
    }
}
```

My pom is:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sf.ehcache</groupId>
        <artifactId>ehcache-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.11</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.2.RELEASE</version>
        <exclusions>
            <!-- Exclude Commons Logging in favor of SLF4j -->
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
```

However each time I am getting an error:

```
    ERROR 2016-11-04 15:07:55,827 org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'managementService' defined in pl.softwarehut.config.SpringWebConfig: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [net.sf.ehcache.management.ManagementService]: Factory method 'managementService' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.ClassCastException: org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheCacheManager cannot be cast to net.sf.ehcache.CacheManager
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:599)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1123)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1018)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:510)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:776)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:861)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:541)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:668)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:540)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:494)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:136)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1194)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1003)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:4921)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5231)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:152)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:724)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:700)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:734)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:596)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDescriptor.run(HostConfig.java:1805)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [net.sf.ehcache.management.ManagementService]: Factory method 'managementService' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.ClassCastException: org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheCacheManager cannot be cast to net.sf.ehcache.CacheManager
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:189)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:588)
    ... 31 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheCacheManager cannot be cast to net.sf.ehcache.CacheManager
```

Do you know why? How to fix it?

Comment: Why you do such a cast `(net.sf.ehcache.CacheManager) ehCacheManager()` in `public ManagementService managementService()` ? `EhCacheCacheManager` contains a reference to `net.sf.ehcache.CacheManager` via `org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheCacheManager#getCacheManager`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you change this line:

```
@Bean
public ManagementService managementService() {
    return new ManagementService((net.sf.ehcache.CacheManager) ehCacheManager(), mBeanServer(), true, true, true, true);
}
```

to

```
@Bean
public ManagementService managementService() {
    return new ManagementService( ehCacheManager().getCac‌​heManager(), mBeanServer(), true, true, true, true);
}
```

should resolve your cast problem.